# Undertanding JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am pretty new to JavaScript, coming from a Java background. I was just playing around with the NodeJS (`"type": "module"`) Express framework but got between two types of ways for writing the methods in JS.

Below are the examples (check comments inline).

**Type 1:**

`main.js`

```
const method1 = () => {
    ...
    method2();
    ...
};

const method2 = () => {
    // this is not exported, so it works as a private method and won't be accessible in other JS files
    ...
};

.
.
.
// likewise there can be many other methods here

export { method1 }; // export other methods as well
```

Then, I can use the `method1` (cannot use `method2` as it is not exported) in any other JS file like below:

`test.js`

```
import { method1 } from './main.js';

method1();
```

---

**Type 2:**

`main.js`

```
class Main {
    
    method1() {
        ...
        method2();
        ...
    }

    #method2() {
        // this is a private method, so won't be accessible outside of this class
        ...
    }

    // likewise other methods here
}

const main = new Main();

export default main;
```

Then, I can use this class instance in any other JS file like below:

`test.js`

```
import main from './main.js';

main.method1();
```

---

**I want to know what is the difference between these two, when to use which, and which is better.**

Comment: This is opinion-based. Even if there is some slight objective difference (like whether a given JS env supports the private method syntax) this isn't going to be able to be definitively answered. This question basically boils down to whether you like OOP's or FP's style encapsulation.

Comment: I understand OOP, but what is FP style?

Comment: Functional programming. In your first example you are using the module system to encapsulate "method2" from code that imports that file. This is more typical in languages that allow you to define standalone functions and/or lack object orientation.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so you mean to say that basically, above both types are the same and can be used by the person's own preference (WRT JS)?

Comment: "Type 1" is not called a *method* at all, since they are not invoked on objects. They simply are *functions* or *procedures*. The closest equivalent in Java would be lambdas.

Comment: Basically yes. Bergi is also correct about terminology, which is why my earlier comment about "method2" had the scare quotes.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I know that about the terminology, it was just I wanted to compare both the types, which I think are mostly same. It just a matter of user's preference.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri The big difference between your snippets is the object. You can instantiate `new Main()` multiple times, and you can keep state in each object separately. If you need to do that, use a `class`. If you don't need multiple instances with different data, and don't need to keep state, you should not use `class`es and go with simple stateless static functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches work fine, but Type 2 is somewhat weird because you're using a class *only* to keep something from being exported.

Classes are usually used to group together *data* (properties on the instance of the class) with *methods* that operate on that data. For a silly example:

```
class NumberMultiplier {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }
  multiply(mult) {
    return this.num * mult;
  }
}
const n = new NumberMultiplier(5);
console.log(n.multiply(10));
```

Above, there is *data* (`this.num`), and there's also a method that operates on the data (`multiply`).

But in your case, you don't look to have instance data - you only want to group functions together, there's not really a reason to use a class. You can consider defining the functions individually - as you did in the first snippet - or you could use a plain object that gets exported, with only the properties you need:

```
const method2 = () => {
};
export default {
  method1() {
    method2();
  }
};
```

If you *do* have persistent data and want to put it on the class instance, using a class and `#` private methods is a possibility (creating a single instance with `new` and then exporting that instance is an example of a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)).

A potential issue to be aware of is that if you use `export default` with an object, there's no way to extract a single property of the export when importing in a single line. That is, if you only have a default export, you can't do something like

```
import { method1 } from './main.js'.default;
```

You could only do

```
import theObj from './main.js';
const { method1 } = theObj;
```

which some would consider to look a bit ugly. Having independent named exports can make it a bit easier for the consumers of a module to import only what they need into standalone identifiers, in a single line.

Comment: The example I given above were just for representation and that's why I didn't include the class variables or such. Ofcourse, we can define the variables in `Type 1` and do not export them, then they will be treated as class's instance's private variables. So, basically I do not see any difference in them.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri The module in your first snippet provides an implicit singleton. Avoid this if you have stateful variables, and obviously it doesn't work if you need multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi and CertainPerformance. Maintaining the state of variables makes an exact difference between the two approaches I guess. This was what I was looking for, Thanks again.

Comment: Apart from that, I am just curious as like in FP style do we have any function or anything which can resemblence with the `constructor`, which just executes once automatically upon that  module loading.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Any top-level code in the module executes when the module is loaded.

Comment: And this code will be executed only once for whole app after startup? I mean regardless of that module being used in multiple different modules, the top-level code will only be executed only once?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri That's right, top-level code runs only once. If you want different users of the module to have their own independent variables, and use the function form, one possibility (that I like) is to export a function that declares variables and returns an object of functions. `export const makeFoo = () => { let fooVar; return { setFooVar(arg) { fooVar = arg; }, getFooVar: () => fooVar } };`

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, didn't get your last point of returning object as functions, but I am now convinced about my doubts. Thanks again. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Classes in JS, unlike your familiarity in Java, are rarely used when not explicitly necessary. Nevertheless, there are situations where OOP in JS could be very useful.

Basically, the first method (**Type 1**) is what you're going to be using/seeing 99% of the time if you're doing just general JS programming such as front-end websites or apps.

If you're i.e. making a game however, you could use OOP to have better control over the different characters/object in your game.

In terms of back-end or on an infrastructural level, it really depends. You could perfectly use classes (**Type 2**) if you're following the [MVC design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), but is again optional.

In the end, it comes down to your own design choice(s). You could go for FP (**T1**) or OOP (**T2**) whenever you like in JS, although there are some 'industry standards' for certain scenarios to decide when to use which.

Comment: Cool, so from the @JaredSmith's comments and your answer, I find that both the above types are similar for JS and it goes to the user's preference. BTW, I am talking about backend only here. Nevertheless, I find `Type2` more appealing to me (my Java habits :P).

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what you are exporting. The **type 1** is more appropriate if you export only one or a few objects. With **type 1**, you can export any primitive type variables or objects and can be used straightaway in the **main.js**.

However, if you want to export many objects and/or variables, then **type 2** makes sense. With **type 2**, all exports are stored in an object, so you have to access them using this object.
Performance-wise both are same.